# When is $AB=I$ for not necessarily square matrices $A$, $B$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have the following matrix equation:

> $$
> \begin{pmatrix}
> 0 & 3 & 0 & 0 \\
> 0 & 0 & 4 & 0 \\
> 0 & 0 & 0 & 5
> \end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix}
> 0 & 0 & 0 \\
> \frac 1 3 & 0 & 0 \\
> 0 & \frac 1 4 & 0 \\
> 0 & 0 & \frac 1 5
> \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
> 1 & 0 & 0 \\
> 0 & 1 & 0 \\
> 0 & 0 & 1
> \end{pmatrix}
> $$

Is there a special name or adjective to describe the relationship between $A$ and $B$?

I also want to know, except orthogonal and unitary matrices, with what else matrices can a identity matrix be produced?

Many thanks!

Comment: @DietrichBurde I think in this case $A$ and $B$ need not be square matrices

Comment: $A$ is sometimes called a "left inverse" of $B$.

Answer (score 2):

If $A$ is an $n\times m$ matrix and $B$ an $m\times n$ matrix, we say $A$ is a left inverse of $B$ and $B$ is a right inverse of $A$ if $AB=I_n$. In this situation, it is not necessarily true that $BA=I_m$ as well, as you can verify in your example.

When $n=m$, we have $AB=I_n$ if and only if $BA=I_n$ and call $A$ *the* inverse of $B$ and $B$ *the* inverse of $A$, since in this case there is only one possible (both sided) inverse matrix. The inverse is then denoted by $B=A^{-1}$, $A=B^{-1}$.

In the case $n\neq m$, left and right inverses are not unique, that is, $AB=I_n$ and $A'B=I_n$ does not imply $A=A'$ (and the same for right inverses).

Given an $n\times m$ matrix $A$, we can find a $B$ such that $AB=I_n$ if and only if the rank of $A$ is equal to $n$.

Given an $m\times n$ matrix $B$, we can find $A$ such that $AB=I_n$ if and only if the kernel of $A$ is trivial, that is, the nullity of $A$ is equal to $0$.